# Log jdupes output in unRAID User Script

Tags: io-redirection

I have an unRAID server and I use `jdupes` to manage duplicate files.
I set up a User Script with `jdupes -rL /dir1 /dir2`. However, the log of the User Script does not display the output of `jdupes`.

`jdupes` output works in the terminal. If I call `stdbuf -oL jdupes -rL /dir1 /dir2 >output.txt 2>&1` from within a script, the output.txt contains the data I need to see.

However, neither method works from within User Scripts. I have also tried

```
output=$(stdbuf -oL jdupes -rL /dir1 /dir2 2>&1)
echo $output
blah=42
echo $blah
```

for which the log file only says `42`. Other things I have tried include writing to a temporary file and reading it again and echoing output to log (but the temp file is created but never written to), writing directly to the log file of User Scripts (no output), and `tee` to file (file created but empty).

All of these methods work when called from the terminal.
I think this is problem is unique to the interaction between unRAID User Scripts and jdupes, but any pointers would help.

**Update:**

So the standard output of `jdupes` is as follows (with comments by me):

```
Scanning: x files, y items (in d specified)                # line 1
Progress [i/j, k pairs matched] n%  (confirm: m%)          # line 2

# output lines (I want to log these)
[SRC] /dir1/file1
----> /dir2/filex1

[SRC] /dir1/file2
----> /dir2/filex2
```

When run from terminal, line 1 and line 2 are displayed in the terminal and updated during runtime. After completion of the run, line 1 and the output lines are displayed.

When run from a terminal and redirected to a file like `jdupes -rfL /dir1 /dir2 >> output.txt`, line 1 and 2 are displayed in the terminal during runtime and after completion, line 1 is in the terminal and output lines are in output.txt. This is exactly what I want to happen.

However, when run from within User Scripts, the log files show absolutely nothing. Using the method in Chris' answer, the log files show the constantly updated lines 1 and 2 during runtime, but after completion of the script, the log file is empty. No line 1, no line 2 and no output lines. I want the output lines alone in the log file.

Hope this makes my question and intentions clearer.

Comment: I'm the author of jdupes. Why are you attempting to log the interactive progress indicator? It uses special characters to overwrite its own lines and is not suitable for logging.

Comment: Hi Jody, didn't expect to run into you here. I wanted to email you about this before posting here, but wasn't sure if it would be appropriate. Updated question with more details. P.S. Read your blog and I think you're awesome.

Comment: This seems like something unique to unRAID. jdupes uses ANSI standard I/O for everything and the final output is always on stdout. The only reason you'd have empty redirected output is if something else is doing it. The shell is generally responsible for setting up redirections. I don't know much about unRAID so I don't know what OS or shell it may be running but I am betting the shell is not obeying your redirections for some reason.

Comment: Ok got it. I will ask for help in the unRAID forums. Thanks for your time.